# duplicate question is missing

Tags: support, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions

What happens if a "Possible Duplicate" Question is missing for a closed question.

here is the link

[c# handle return value and execute code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282714/c-sharp-handle-return-value-and-execute-code)

now under [Revision List](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6282714/revisions)

So is this a bug on SO.

Comment: Not a bug; the linked question was deleted. That *is* confusing for not 10K users, but it is otherwise working as designed.

Comment: what if these things can be checked on delete. can be redesigned that way.

Comment: It isn't even a duplicate. The question is asking about the performance difference. The deleted duplicate is about coding-style.

Comment: What if we want to reopen that question? You can raise that here on Meta. We can also edit the link to no longer point to a 404, vote to delete the question, or link it to a different dupe. In any case, this needs community intervention.

Comment: Note - the question is now reopened, to see what was going on you have to go to its [Revisions list](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6282714/revisions)

Comment: @binil - They are checked on delete, you get a warning that other posts are linked to the one you vote to delete.

Answer (score 1):

[Look carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36707/revisions), at the revision history, and you'll notice that [the question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282714/c-sharp-handle-return-value-and-execute-code) was for some period of time (although now re-opened) marked as a duplicate of a question that later got deleted. If a question is deleted, unless you have 10k repuation or are a moderator, you will not be able to view the deleted question.

The question that had the question you mentioned as a duplicate is no longer deleted (it was undeleted).

This is not a bug, it is just that a question that was marked as a duplicate of another question had its question that it was marked a duplicate of deleted.

At this moment in the fabric of space time, the question you mentioned is no longer marked as a duplicate of the question that got deleted, and the question that got deleted is no longer deleted.